# How to Fetch image from Photo Library or Camera with Edit functionality like iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, camera, ios11, swift4

I am developing an app in Xcode 9 and Swift 4. The app allows the user to use their device camera or photo library to select a photo, however, it will not display the edit button to allow the user to edit the image from within the app as it does when the user is not within an app.
I have added the privacy permissions in the plist file and I have searched StackOverflow, Google, Youtube, and this developer forum, but cannot find anything of a recent nature. I did find a question from 5 years and 7 months ago which stated that it was an Apple proprietary functionality.  I was hoping that  something  has changed to allow this functionality from with an app. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks !
Tom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to write an image editor yourself or use an existing libraries, 
Here is an example to get you started:

https://github.com/eventtus/photo-editor

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but I will take this as the answer to my question. Thanks for the update and the link to a starter example.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer and for providing the link ! I very much appreciate your willingness to assist !

Comment: @twglodek
I can help you with the app, let's talk about it over email (Hassan.3skandari@gmail.com)